# Can two Update Contact activities in Journey Builder write data to the same row in a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

The Update Contact activity has a limit of 5 fields that can be selected in the interface and updated in a data extension. To overcome this I tried to use two activities that insert/update a row and update it in the second block to write more data.

**Example configuration**:

*Update contact 1:*

- `PrimaryKey = A`
- `Value_A = "Update 1"`

*Update contact 2:*

- `PrimaryKey = A`
- `Value_B = "Update 2"`

**Result**

This in theory should give me the a data extension row where both `Value_A` and `Value_B` are not null, but it does not work this way - only the first Update Contact block is being executed (which leaves the `Value_B = null`) - changing the order of the activities confirms that.

Is there some way of overcoming this?

I tried adding joins between the two update activities to see if this somehow could affect the case, but that does not help - still only one Update Contact activity is writing to the data extension.

**Additional detail:**

- The journey is API triggered (for the sake of testing), but would normally be using SF data as a source.
- Not all values written to the DE by the Update Contact activity are static. The `PrimaryKey` is taken dynamically from the Journey Data with syntax like `{{Event."APIEvent-a3e1f543-4352-4a5f-9df0-8a28e450ac3a"."ContactKey"}}`.
- In this test journey `Value_A` and `Value_B` are static
- All values mentioned are strings that should be written to corresponding text columns of a data extension

Answer (score 1):

A possible hack could be: update a single field with a json object:

PrimaryKey = A
Values = { "Value_A": "Update 1", "Value_B": "Update 2", etc etc }

Then, via a SSJS script activity deserialize the object and impact the specific columns.

Comment: That's a good idea!